# Python - error in pandas (during loop processing files)

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I get freaky error while processing (extracting data from CSV files) I can't understand. I'm beginner and I wrote some code to extract mri-generated onset times and durations. My code (below) runs through all (144) csv files as input file, extracts info I need and saves it as csv in output directory. Problem is that error comes up after 10 files are processed. I really don't understand what's going on since all csv input files are formatted identically. Can you help me understanding the error and how to fix it? 
The code works as it should on single file, only problem with extracting rows is when loop goes through multiple files. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np  
import csv
import glob
IN="/Users/*****/Documents/LMG_Env/RSA/RSA_mri/events/behavioral_stimuli_computer/CSVlog/" # points to csv files
OUT= "/Users/*****/Documents/LMG_Env/RSA/RSA_mri/events/onsets/" # outputted.
file_list = os.path.join(IN, '*.csv')

for infile in glob.glob(file_list):

    # open log file and load it into table from 3rd row.
    in_txt = pd.read_csv(infile, names=['Subject','Trial','Event Type','Code','Time','TTime','Uncertainty','Duration','Uncertainty_1','ReqTime','ReqDur','Stim Type','Pair Index'], skiprows=3, delimiter=',')
    df = pd.DataFrame(in_txt,columns=['Subject','Trial','Event Type','Code','Time','TTime','Uncertainty','Duration','Uncertainty_1','ReqTime','ReqDur','Stim Type','Pair Index'])

    # for each row in table extract only columns: Trial, Event type, Code, Time, Duration
    columns = df.columns
    extract_column = df[['Trial','Event Type', 'Code', 'Time','Duration']]
    extract_column = extract_column.set_index('Event Type') #changing index to Event Type

    # extract only rows with Event Type: Picture.
    extract_rows = extract_column.loc['Picture']

    #recalculare time & duration into seconds.
    extract_rows.loc[:,'Time'] = extract_rows['Time'].div(10000) #to seconds
    extract_rows.loc[:,'Duration'] = extract_rows['Duration'].div(10000) #to seconds

    # save file in OUT as tsv (tab separated vectors)
    filename = 'sub-' + os.path.splitext( os.path.basename(infile))[0] + '_events' + '.csv'
    filename = os.path.join(OUT, filename)
    extract_rows.to_csv(filename, index=False)
    print(filename)
```

and the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Picture'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-640c70c49427> in <module>
     11 
     12 # extract only rows with Event Type: Picture.
---> 13     extract_rows = extract_column.loc['Picture']
     14 
     15 #recalculare time & duration into seconds.

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1498 
   1499             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1500             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1501 
   1502     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1911         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1912         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1913         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1914 
   1915 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    139             raise IndexingError('no slices here, handle elsewhere')
    140 
--> 141         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    142 
    143     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=None):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3583                                                       drop_level=drop_level)
   3584         else:
-> 3585             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3586 
   3587             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Picture'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(in_txt,columns=['Subject','Trial','Event Type','Code','Time','TTime','Uncertainty','Duration','Uncertainty_1','ReqTime','ReqDur','Stim Type','Pair Index'])
```

That dataframe does not have a column named `Picture`.

Comment: pls check ,"Picture" in extract_column.index

Comment: yes that line extracts rows (not columns) from column 'Event Type'.